# Elasticsearch Segments

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with 12 shards allocated in 3 nodes. The index has around 5 millions of elements. Yesterday, these 5 milions of elements had a size of around 35Gb, and if I could reindex all these elements with the new reduced size of each of them, the total size of the index would be around 10Gb.

The problem is that, if I reindex these items inside the existing items, by using upserts, so updating them all, the index size does not reduce at all.

I've been checking the _forcemerge Elasticsearch API, but ATM I'm not using any kind of replicas, and they don't really recommend using this API in a master set of shards.

I'm learning the insides of Elasticsearch, and I'm actually working with a PROD environment, so I can't really clean-and-reindex.

Can anyone send me some light?

Comment: May I ask you how did you estimate the new could-be size, 10Gb, after reindex? How do you measure thr size of the current index?

Comment: Is the index size after indexing it in a new index.

Comment: Did you consider [reindexing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/docs-reindex.html), using the new index and deleting the old one?

Comment: Then I'd have another index, not the one I need.

Comment: You could use [index aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) and switch it to point to the new index, if this is the matter of naming.